# How to edit particular cell value on click of cell and set back on lost focus of cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

In ASP.NET grid view control, Need edit cell value as below way:

1. On single click of particular cell, it should show the `textbox` & allow to change the value. And once cursor/focus move of the cell then convert back to grid view cell (hide/remove the textbox).

when user click on common `save` button click event, will post bulk data to server to get it save.

How to achieve above function for allowing edit the cell value on click of cell click?

note:I found this option easily available in infragistic but need this achieve in asp.net grid view control (.NET FX 3.5).have not wish to use the in-built edit, delete and update buttons of gridview.

Thank You

Comment: why it downvotes... I dont' want to use - inline edit feature of gridview as per requirement design.

Comment: Please show us your code

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using CSS designs also. All you need is display all data in textboxes rather than labels and then upon button click fire a bulk update method. I can see a [nice post by Scott Mitchell here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/data-access/editing-and-deleting-data-through-the-datalist/performing-batch-updates-cs).

Comment: do you mean, directly show the textbox as grid view cell ? Is it possible to handle gridview cell event and on click of cell- show the textbox and lost focus/curose from cell, reset back to grid view cell (hide the textbox) ?

Answer (score 0):

I just kept directly textbox as column instead of adding cell click event as shown below:

```
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name Field">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtnameField" value='<%# Eval("nameField") %>' Width="218px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <HeaderStyle />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Thanks